# How to load map with Twebbrowser

Tags: android, google-maps, delphi, twebbrowser

The map in question is here, [map](http://www.smartpavilion.com/map). I can load it from any browser such as Chrome, but when I try to load it from my Delphi application with TWebBrowser, it's blocked by google. It says *API key needed*.

I load it simply with TWebBrowser like this :

```
webbrowser1.url:='www.smartpavilion.com/map/';
```

Are there any tricks so that TWebBrowser can load it like any browser ?

Comment: A simple google search for this issue will bring up dozens of sites\blogs\etc where you can find the answer. What you have done? Have you registered and get the API key from google?

Comment: no, i dont use api key for the map. i use
`code` <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"  type="text/javascript"></script>. and its working in any browser. but it's blocked when i load it in Twebbrowser. I just want to make a browser which the map can loaded. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The new V3 the key is recommended, but not required. I tried your address in a quick form and it came right up.

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.navigate('www.smartpavilion.com/map/');
end;
```

I am using Rad Studio 10 Seattle, for reference.

Comment: But i try the same code as android application it's blocked..  May be we have to add map api key at xml manifest for user permission to access gmap service. But how?